# Dynamic interceptFrom()

Tags: apache-camel

[The documentation for "intercepts"](http://camel.apache.org/intercept.html) says:

> The interceptSendToEndpoint is dynamic hence it will also trigger if a
> dynamic URI is constructed that Camel was not aware of at startup
> time.
>
> The interceptFrom is not dynamic as it only intercepts input to
> routes registered as routes in CamelContext.

Is there an idiomatic way to create something equivalent to a dynamic "from intercept"?

Stepping back, here is what I want to do: intercept every time a message is written to or read from a jms component, where the URI matches a certain wildcard pattern.

Comment: Just use both of them interceptFrom and interceptSendTo and let them route to the same route / call same bean or whatever

Comment: My question is how to trigger the intercerptFrom() for routes that are not set up yet. I've edited the question to add I want to set up something like this:     interceptFrom("xyzQueue:*)... ,,,     intercetSendToEndpoint("xyzQueue:*) ... ... 
So that I intercept every message read or written to a particular component, in any route that already exists or will be created later.

Answer (score 1):

Then use something else than interceptFrom, such as event notifier where you can get a notification when sending/sent/received etc.

- http://camel.apache.org/advanced-configuration-of-camelcontext-using-spring.html
- http://camel.apache.org/eventnotifier-to-log-details-about-all-sent-exchanges.html